# Связи в Pivot таблице. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relation, many-to-many

У меня есть связь MtoM, через pivot таблицу в Laravel. Взять дополнительные поля из pivot таблицы не составляет труда (withPivot), а вот как быть если в pivot у меня тоже связь - не понятно.

Comment: создай класс для pivot таблицы и наследуйся от класса Pivot (вместо Model, как у обычных моделей). При объвлении отношений в моделях используй метод using(MyPivotClass::class). Ну и используй отношение hasManyThrough через pivot'ную таблицу. Думаю вполне рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как я реализовал это у себя.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models
https://github.com/ajcastro/eager-load-pivot-relations

```php
class Template extends Model
{
    use EagerLoadPivotTrait;

    public function questions(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class)
            ->using('App\Models\QuestionTemplatePivot')
            ->has('section')
            ->withPivot('id');
    }

}

class Question extends Model
{
    use EagerLoadPivotTrait;

    public function templates(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Template::class)
            ->using('App\Models\QuestionTemplatePivot')
            ->withPivot('id');
    }

}

class QuestionTemplatePivot extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'question_template';

    public function positions(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Position::class, 'position_question_template', 'question_template_id', 'position_id');
    }
}
```

Теперь можно вот так получить нужные связи:

```php
        $positions = $template->questions()
            ->with('pivot.positions')
            ->first()
            ->pivot
            ->positions;
```